# Application Crashes while changing activities

Tags: android

I've been working on support for multiple screens in my app. However, when my screen is detected as a 480x800 screen, it switches to the Activity for that resolution, but at that point it crashes...

This is the detect.java, where It makes a decision based on the screen resolution:

```
package com.example.mywallpapers;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class Detect extends Activity {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        int width = 0;
        Point size = new Point();
        WindowManager w = getWindowManager();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {

            w.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);

            width = size.x;
        } else {
            Display d = w.getDefaultDisplay();
            width = d.getWidth();
        }
        if (width == 480) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Detect.this, SevenTwentyOne.class));



        } else if (width == 720) {
            startActivity(new Intent("com.example.mywallpapers.FOUREIGHTONE"));
        } else {
            startActivity(new Intent("com.example.mywallpapers.FOUREIGHTONE"));
        }

    }



    }
```

This is my SevenTwentyOne class (which isn't for the 1280x720 resolution, but for the 480x800)

```
package com.example.mywallpapers;

import java.io.IOException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView;

public class SevenTwentyOne extends Activity {

    ImageView display;
    int toPhone;
    private MoPubView mAdView;
    MediaPlayer knopje;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.foureightyeighthundredeen);

        mAdView = (MoPubView) findViewById(R.id.adview);
        mAdView.setAdUnitId("e95a36beb72611e281c11231392559e4"); // Enter your
                                                                    // Ad Unit
                                                                    // ID from
        // www.mopub.com
        mAdView.loadAd();

        display = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.WaP49);
        Button image1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.WaP50);
        Button image2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.WaP51);
        Button image3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.WaP52);
        Button image4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.WaP53);
        Button image5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.WaP54);
        Button image6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.WaP55);
        Button image7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.WaP56);
        Button image8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.WaP57);
        Button image9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.WaP58);
        Button image10 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.WaP59);
        Button image11 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.WaP60);
        Button image12 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.WaP61);
        Button image13 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.WaP62);
        Button image14 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.WaP63);
        Button image15 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.WaP64);
        Button image16 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.WaP65);
        Button image17 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.WaP66);
        Button image18 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.WaP67);
        Button image19 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.WaP68);
        Button image20 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.WaP69);
        Button image21 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.WaP70);
        Button image22 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.WaP71);
        Button image23 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.WaP72);
        Button image24 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.WaP73);
        Button image25 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.WaP74);
        Button image26 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.WaP75);
        Button image27 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.WaP76);
        Button image28 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.WaP77);
        Button image29 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.WaP78);
        Button image30 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.WaP79);
        Button image31 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.WaP80);
        Button image32 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.WaP81);
        Button image33 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.WaP82);
        Button image34 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.WaP83);
        Button image35 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.WaP84);
        Button image36 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.WaP85);
        Button image37 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.WaP86);
        Button image38 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.WaP87);
        Button image39 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.WaP88);
        Button image40 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.WaP89);
        Button image41 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.WaP90);
        Button image42 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.WaP91);
        Button image43 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.WaP92);
        Button image44 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.WaP93);
        Button image45 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.WaP94);
        Button image46 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.WaP95);
        Button image47 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.WaP96);
        Button setWall = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SetWallPaperButton);

        toPhone = R.drawable.a_aardbeien;
        knopje = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.button);


        image1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { // Line 90

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.aardmannetje);
                toPhone = R.drawable.a_aardmannetje;
                knopje.start();
            }
        });
        image2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.aardbeien);
                toPhone = R.drawable.a_aardbeien;
                knopje.start();
            }
        });
        image3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.android);
                toPhone = R.drawable.a_android;
                knopje.start();
            }
        });
        image4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.batman);
                toPhone = R.drawable.a_batman;
                knopje.start();
            }
        });
        image5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.bij);
                toPhone = R.drawable.a_bij;
                knopje.start();
            }
        });
        image6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.blaadjes);
                toPhone = R.drawable.a_blaadjes;
                knopje.start();
            }
        });
        image7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.bliksem);
                toPhone = R.drawable.a_bliksem;
                knopje.start();
            }
        });
        image8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.bloemblaadjes);
                toPhone = R.drawable.a_bloemblaadjes;
                knopje.start();
            }
        });
        image9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.bloemetjes);
                toPhone = R.drawable.a_bloemetjes;
                knopje.start();
            }
        });
        image10.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.blokjes);
                toPhone = R.drawable.a_blokjes;
                knopje.start();
            }
        });
        image11.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.bubbels);
                toPhone = R.drawable.a_bubbels;
                knopje.start();
            }
        });
        image12.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.chocolade);
                toPhone = R.drawable.a_chocolade;
                knopje.start();
            }
        });
        image13.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.closeuproos);
                toPhone = R.drawable.a_closeuproos;
                knopje.start();
            }
        });
        image14.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.druppels);
                toPhone = R.drawable.a_druppels;
                knopje.start();
            }
        });
        image15.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.duinen);
                toPhone = R.drawable.a_duinen;
                knopje.start();
            }
        });
        image16.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.frambozen);
                toPhone = R.drawable.a_frambozen;
                knopje.start();
            }
        });
        image17.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.gekleurdeblokjes);
                toPhone = R.drawable.a_gekleurdeblokjes;
                knopje.start();
            }
        });
        image18.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.gekleurdeballetjes);
                toPhone = R.drawable.a_gekleurderondjes;
                knopje.start();
            }
        });
        image19.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.gekleurderoos);
                toPhone = R.drawable.a_gekleurderoos;
                knopje.start();
            }
        });
        image20.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.geld);
                toPhone = R.drawable.a_geld;
                knopje.start();
            }
        });
        image21.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.gitaar);
                toPhone = R.drawable.a_gitaar;
                knopje.start();
            }
        });
        image22.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.graslucht);
                toPhone = R.drawable.a_luchtgras;
                knopje.start();
            }
        });
        image23.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.hartjes);
                toPhone = R.drawable.a_hartjes;
                knopje.start();
            }
        });
        image24.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.hartjesdruppel);
                toPhone = R.drawable.a_hartjesdruppel;
                knopje.start();
            }
        });
        image25.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.ijsjes);
                toPhone = R.drawable.a_ijsjes;
                knopje.start();
            }
        });
        image26.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.jellybeans);
                toPhone = R.drawable.a_jellybeans;
                knopje.start();
            }
        });
        image27.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.kerstballen);
                toPhone = R.drawable.a_kerstballen;
                knopje.start();
            }
        });
        image28.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.kleurenspiraal);
                toPhone = R.drawable.a_kleurenspiraal;
                knopje.start();
            }
        });
        image29.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.kleurenhout);
                toPhone = R.drawable.a_kleurhout;
                knopje.start();
            }
        });
        image30.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.kleurstrepen);
                toPhone = R.drawable.a_kleurstrepen;
                knopje.start();
            }
        });
        image31.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.kunst);
                toPhone = R.drawable.a_kunst;
                knopje.start();
            }
        });
        image32.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.lente);
                toPhone = R.drawable.a_lente;
                knopje.start();
            }
        });
        image33.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.muziek);
                toPhone = R.drawable.a_muziek;
                knopje.start();
            }
        });
        image34.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.panterprint);
                toPhone = R.drawable.a_panterprint;
                knopje.start();
            }
        });

        image35.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.parijs);
                toPhone = R.drawable.a_parijs;
                knopje.start();
            }
        });
        image36.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.piano);
                toPhone = R.drawable.a_piano;
                knopje.start();
            }
        });
        image37.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.rozen);
                toPhone = R.drawable.a_rozen;
                knopje.start();
            }
        });
        image38.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.rozepaarsebloemetjes);
                toPhone = R.drawable.a_rozepaarsebloemetjes;
                knopje.start();
            }
        });
        image39.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.stenen);
                toPhone = R.drawable.a_stenen;
                knopje.start();
            }
        });
        image40.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.strand);
                toPhone = R.drawable.a_strand;
                knopje.start();
            }
        });
        image41.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.streepjes);
                toPhone = R.drawable.a_streepjes;
                knopje.start();
            }
        });
        image42.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.struik);
                toPhone = R.drawable.a_struik;
                knopje.start();
            }
        });
        image43.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.tjahoezullenwehetnoemen);
                toPhone = R.drawable.a_tjahoezullenwehetnoemen;
                knopje.start();
            }
        });
        image44.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.tulpen);
                toPhone = R.drawable.a_tulpen;
                knopje.start();
            }
        });
        image45.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.veren);
                toPhone = R.drawable.a_veren;
                knopje.start();
            }
        });
        image46.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.watermannetje);
                toPhone = R.drawable.a_watermannetje;
                knopje.start();
            }
        });
        image47.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.zwartwit);
                toPhone = R.drawable.a_zwartwit;
                knopje.start();
            }
        });
        setWall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Bitmap whatever = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getResources()
                        .openRawResource(toPhone));
                try {

                    getApplicationContext().setWallpaper(whatever);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {knopje.start();
                    Toast my_toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wallpaper Set!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    my_toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                    my_toast.show();;
                }


            }

        });
    };

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        mAdView.destroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mAdView.destroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        mAdView = (MoPubView) findViewById(R.id.adview);
        mAdView.setAdUnitId("e95a36beb72611e281c11231392559e4"); // Enter your
                                                                    // Ad Unit
                                                                    // ID from
        // www.mopub.com
        mAdView.loadAd();
    }

}
```

Whenever I test my app on an 480x800 phone, it crashes with an NullPointerExeption. Any idea where that one might come from?

This is the logCat:

```
05-15 11:27:47.600: E/AndroidRuntime(31642): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-15 11:27:47.600: E/AndroidRuntime(31642): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mywallpapers/com.example.mywallpapers.SevenTwentyOne}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-15 11:27:47.600: E/AndroidRuntime(31642):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
05-15 11:27:47.600: E/AndroidRuntime(31642):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
05-15 11:27:47.600: E/AndroidRuntime(31642):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
05-15 11:27:47.600: E/AndroidRuntime(31642):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
05-15 11:27:47.600: E/AndroidRuntime(31642):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-15 11:27:47.600: E/AndroidRuntime(31642):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-15 11:27:47.600: E/AndroidRuntime(31642):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
05-15 11:27:47.600: E/AndroidRuntime(31642):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-15 11:27:47.600: E/AndroidRuntime(31642):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-15 11:27:47.600: E/AndroidRuntime(31642):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
05-15 11:27:47.600: E/AndroidRuntime(31642):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
05-15 11:27:47.600: E/AndroidRuntime(31642):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-15 11:27:47.600: E/AndroidRuntime(31642): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-15 11:27:47.600: E/AndroidRuntime(31642):    at com.example.mywallpapers.SevenTwentyOne.onCreate(SevenTwentyOne.java:90)
05-15 11:27:47.600: E/AndroidRuntime(31642):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
05-15 11:27:47.600: E/AndroidRuntime(31642):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
05-15 11:27:47.600: E/AndroidRuntime(31642):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
05-15 11:27:47.600: E/AndroidRuntime(31642):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: The null pointer in the logcat says its at line 90 in SevenTwentyOne.java, can you highlight that line?

Comment: post your "foureightyeighthundredeen" layout file

Comment: do you have button Wap50 in your layout file

Comment: I'm sorry, that is not possible, I would get too many characters in the question body

Comment: without the xml, the most likely answer is @Iftikar Urrhman Khan comment. That Wap50 isn't in your layout as findViewById() will return null if the view isn't found.

Comment: Fixed it, I set the contentView to the wrong xml file, so when I called those buttons, they didn't exist in the view. Fixed it now :D